# Can all linear operators on functions be represented as a convolution of the input function with the operator's impulse response?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, dirac-delta

Where $f, g$ are functions, $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta distribution ('aka Delta function'), and L is a linear (LTI) operator,

if $g = L(f)$,  then can we say in all cases $g = Li * f$ , 
where $ Li $ is defined as $L(\delta)$, i.e. the impulse response?

My questions: Is this true?

Any references would be appreciated.

Linear operator References:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearOperator.html
http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/quantrev/node14.html
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Linear_operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $L$ is well-defined linear operator $L^1(\mathbb{R}) \to L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $ then $L[f(y)](x) = h \ast f(x)$ for some $h \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $$\forall a, \qquad L[f(y-a)](x) = L[f(y)](x-a)$$ That's why we say "linear **and** time-invariant [(LTI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_theory) operators".

The same theoy of LTI operators works in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}),L^2(\mathbb{R}), C^0(\mathbb{R}), D(\mathbb{R})$  and $D'(\mathbb{R})$. The Dirac delta $\delta$ belongs to this last space : it is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Comment: Is h the impulse response of L?  Is it always the impulse response?

Comment: @user45664 Yes $L$ is LTI and if it converges then $h(x) = L[\delta](x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} L[\frac{1_{|y| <\epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}](x)$

Comment: If L is LTI and it also converges, then is h (the impulse response) unique? :)

Comment: @user45664 Assume that $f \ast h = 0$ for every $f$ so that $h(x) = 0$ "everywhere". Then $h(0) = 0$ or $h(0) = 1$ doesn't change anything under convolution. So it is unique up to isolated values (sets of measure $0$).

Comment: So you need to state it like this : if $L$ is LTI and $h(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} L[\frac{1_{|y| <\epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}](x)$ is well-defined, then $L[f] = f \ast h$ @user45664

Comment: I don't understand the limit (particularly the numerator term in the argument for L).  I assume the argument is a rectangular pulse that approaches the Dirac distribution.

Comment: @user45664 Yes, this is a rectangle approaching $\delta$ in the limit, and a rigorous definition of $\delta$.

Comment: I have used your answer for part of a proof in a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2247191/147776  :)

Comment: is there a 'name' (theorem, or ..?) for what you stated in your answer? :)